# Automatically disable browser cache in chrome while running tests using protractor

Tags: selenium, caching, selenium-chromedriver, protractor, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to run tests using protractor but i need to disable the browser cache in order to test some things. I do not want chrome to load the resources from browser cache instead i want it it to send the requests to server and download them. I have tried the following options as part of protractor capabilities but nothing seems to be working,

````
'--disable-cache',
'--disable-application-cache',
'--disable-offline-load-stale-cache',
'--disk-cache-size=0'```
````

Answer (score 0):

what if you just run the tests in incognito? that shouldn't save nor reuse the cache

you can do it by passing `--headless` to chrome args

Comment: Still browser cache is gonna be used if i navigate to a page which uses the cached resource as part of the same test